# Python: Finding matching parenthesis in a string and comparing results

Tags: python

Need help solving the below code.

```
def matching_parens(s):
    """
    Returns True if the string s has a matching pair of parentheses.

    A matching pair pair of parentheses is an open parens '(' followed by a closing
    parens ')'.  Any thing can be between the two pair (including other parens).

    Example: matching_parens('A (B) C') returns True
    Example: matching_parens('A )B( C') returns False

    Parameter s: The string to check
    Precondition: s is a string (possibly empty)
    """
    # Search for the first open parens '('
    first = introcs.find_str(s,'/(')+1
    print(first)
    # Search for the first close parens ')' AFTER the open parens
    second = introcs.find_str(s,'/)',first)
    print(second)
    # Compare both searches to -1 and return True if BOTH are not -1
    first == second
```

I am getting the following when I execute this in the terminal:

```
>>> funcs.matching_parens('abc')
0
-1
>>> funcs.matching_parens('')
0
-1
>>> funcs.matching_parens('abc(d)')
0
-1
>>>
```

The call matching_parens('') returned None instead of False.

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but definitely not solving per the specification with what I have tried so far.  Any help or advice would be awesome.  (Note: I cannot use 'if' statements in this exercise I am doing for class)

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any feedback for the last boolean because you didn't specify the `return` statement, so just replace `first == second` with **`return first == second`**.

That been said, I find your approach to the problem kind of inusual and you just don't need external libs to do such a simple task:

```
def matching_parens(s):
    try:
        opened, closed = s.index("("), s.index(")")
        return closed > opened
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

What does this function do? It searches for the two brackets and finds their position indices in the string `s`; if the position of the `closed` bracked is higher than that of the `opened` bracket return **`True`**, otherwise **`False`**. Also, if at least one of the indices was not found, return **`False`** as well.

As you can see it's a pretty clean, striaght-forward code, without ext libs and complications, and as requested without explicit `if` statements.